# determining the independence of coin flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

i'm a bit confused by this example.
what confuses me the most is how to calculate Pr(E<sub>1</sub>), Pr(E<sub>2</sub>), Pr(E<sub>3</sub>), can someone explain

---

A fair coin is flipped 3 times. If (F<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>, F<sub>3</sub>) denotes a typical flip sequence, let E<sub>1</sub> denote the event that at least two of the F<sub>i</sub>'s are Heads, let E<sub>2</sub> denote the event that exactly two of the F<sub>i</sub>'s are Heads, and let E<sub>3</sub> denote the event that all the F<sub>i</sub> are the same. Which of the pairs of these three events are independent?

Solution:
The only pair that is independent is E<sub>1</sub> and E<sub>3</sub>.

Since Pr(E<sub>1</sub>) = (1/2)<sup>3</sup> + (3 choose 2)(1/2)<sup>3</sup> = 1/2
and
Pr(E<sub>3</sub>) = 2* (1/2)<sup>3</sup> = 1/4, so

Pr(E<sub>1</sub> ∩ E<sub>3</sub>) = Pr(all heads) = 1/8 = Pr(E<sub>1</sub>)Pr(E<sub>3</sub>), while Pr(E<sub>1</sub> ∩ E<sub>2</sub>)=Pr(E<sub>2</sub>) and Pr (E<sub>2</sub> ∩ E<sub>3</sub>)=0

Answer (score 2):

Record the result of the coin flips as a string of length $3$ made of of the letters H and/or T. Such a word records the results, in order, of the coin tosses. For example, HHT says we got a head then a head then a tail.

There are $(2)(2)(2)$ such sequences. They are all **equally likely**.

Now consider the event $E_1$, which says that at least two of the results are heads. We can list explicitly the outcomes that make $E_1$ happen. They are HHH, HHT, HTH, and THH. So in $4$ of the $8$ equally likely possibilities, the event $E_1$ happens. Thus $\Pr(E_1)=\frac{4}{8}$.

Let us do this a *slightly* different way, without explicit listing. There is $1$ way we could have $3$ heads. For $2$ heads, the **locations** of the H can be chosen in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways. Thus the total number of patterns in which $E_1$ happens is $1+\binom{3}{2}$.

Now let us do the same thing in more probabilistic language. Each string of length $3$ has probability $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$. There is $1$ string with all $H$, and there are $\binom{3}{2}$ strings with two H and a T, so the probability of $E_1$ is $\left(1+\binom{3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$.

Now to check whether two events $A$ and $B$ based on the above coin tossing are independent, all we have to do is to check whether $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. If we have equality, then $A$ and $B$ are independent. If we do not have equality, then $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

Since we can determine any of these probabilities by counting, checking for independence is mechanical, and quick.